# tikz /.pic with double rotate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

dear tikzperts: how would I keep the orientation of the text in the box, so that the rotate inside the .pic will be additive to the one in the main text.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  testboxtext/.pic={
    \draw[black, fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (60,40);
    \draw[fill=white] (20,20) rectangle (25,35) node[pos=0.5,rotate=90] { some text };
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1, gray, very thin] (-1,-1) grid (101,101);
  \pic[rotate=90] at (10,10) {testboxtext};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It's almost as if I need an "inner rotate" and an "outer rotate", or double rotate, so that I do not get the override.

advice appreciated.

Comment: I can't even see any text when I compile your example. What does it look like for you?

Comment: Default units for  coordinates in TikZare cm!

Comment: was not the best metrics, of course.  answer is clear, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it hard to believe this is what you really want, but I can't currently find another interpretation of your question.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
  testboxtext/.pic={%
    code={
      \tikzset{%
        test box text/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [black, fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (6,4);
      \draw [fill=white, draw=red] (2,2) rectangle (2.5,3.5) node [rotate=90+\additionalrotation, pos=.5] { some text };
    }
  },
  test box text/.search also={/tikz},
  test box text/.cd,
  rotate/.store in=\additionalrotation,
  rotate=0,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (-1,-1) grid (11,11);
  \pic  at (5,5) {testboxtext};
  \pic  at (1,1) {testboxtext={rotate=90}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotate and rotate again]

Note that I greatly reduced the size of your rectangles since the text was otherwise literally not appearing at all since it was so tiny. I can only assume that you have one of these swish monitors the size of a football field. Since I don't, those dimensions were unmanageably large for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to ensure the correct rotation of the node text within the `\pic` environment would be passing the `[every node/.style={transform shape}]` option to the tikz picture:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
  testboxtext/.pic={%
    code={
      \tikzset{%
        test box text/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [black, fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (6,4);
      \draw [fill=white, draw=red] (2,2) rectangle (2.5,3.5) node [rotate=90+\additionalrotation, pos=.5] { some text };
    }
  },
  test box text/.search also={/tikz},
  test box text/.cd,
  rotate/.store in=\additionalrotation,
  rotate=0,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (-1,-1) grid (11,11);
  \pic  at (5,5) {testboxtext};
  \pic[rotate=90]  at (3,1) {testboxtext};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={transform shape}]
  \draw [help lines] (-1,-1) grid (11,11);
  \pic  at (5,5) {testboxtext};
  \pic[rotate=90]  at (3,1) {testboxtext};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]